# How to count turns in python 2.7

Tags: python

I want a turn counter that counts 1 turn for the explore and hunt option only. And have it add to the current age. How can I do that? I'm using python 2.7. Here's the important parts of the code:

```
from main import name
import os
import random


kenyan_sand_boa = {
    "snek": "kenyan sand boa",
    "prey": "mice, " "birds, " "lizards",
    "biome": "desert",
    "predators": "desert monitor lizard",
    "adult age": 156,
    "baby size": 10,
    "adult size": 20,
    "current size": 10,
    "current age": "0",
    "name": name,
}


os.system('cls')
def menu():
        os.system('cls')
        print '''Now that you have chosen what snek to be, you have a couple 
options
1. Read info about kenyan sand boas.
2. Explore.
3. Hunt.
4. View inventory.
5. Save.
6. Exit.
'''

loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    menu()
    choice = int(raw_input())

    if choice == 1:
        #information about kenyan sand boas
    if choice == 2:
        #exploring
    if choice == 3:
        #huntinng
    if choice == 4:
        #view inventory
    else:
        menu()
```

Comment: trun = 0; ..... if .... turn+=1 ?

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly.

Comment: It might be useful to have `INFO = 1`, `EXPLORING = 2`, `HUNTING = 3` and `INVENTORY = 4` at the top. This would allow you to do `if choice == INFO:` etc.. Also, you can change all `if`s after the first to `elif`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `turn=0`

In your explore/hunt cases, add the following:

```
turn = turn+1 
kenyan_sand_boa["current age"] = kenyan_sand_boa["current age"]+1
```

Might have to define the age as an int, as it currently is a string, but this code will get the job done once you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Within your `while` code set turn to 0.

```
while loop == 1:
    turn = 0
    menu()
    # ...
```

Since you're incrementing the age as well, it would be better to set `"current age"` to `0` instead of `"0"`.
Increment `"current age"` and `turn` by one in your hunting and exploring `if` clauses. (would be more pythonic to use `elif` instead)

```
elif choice == 2:
    turn += 1
    kenyan_sand_boa["current age"] += 1
    # exploring
elif choice == 3:
    turn += 1
    kenyan_sand_boa["current age"] += 1
    # hunting
```